# Why should we subtract 1 to get maximum number in bits

Tags: binary

I'm reading [this](http://www.programminglogic.com/how-computers-represent-negative-binary-numbers/) article and it says that:

> This means that an unsigned **INT** can go up to $4,294,967,296$ (which is
>   $2^{32}$ $– 1$). You need to subtract one because the result of $2^32$ starts
>   from $1$, while the first binary representation is $0$.

I have hard time understanding what is meant by the last sentence, can someone please explain?

Comment: Stick to 2 bits: the possibilities are 00,01,10,11. The number 4 would need an extra bit: 100.

Comment: The biggest decimal value represented in four digits is $$9999 = 10^4 - 1$$ HTH.

Comment: @almagest, so it's four combinations and it seems to be calculated using the formula of `Permutations with Repetition` mentioned [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html), correct?

Comment: Your confusion is in place. The statement "$4,294,967,296$ (which is $2^{32}–1$)" is plain wrong.

Comment: @barakmanos, that's what an article states. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: That's why I said 'your confusion is in place'. I cannot elaborate on "$4,294,967,296=2^{32}-1$" in any other manner I'm afraid.

Comment: @barakmanos, but you said it's wrong, why?

Comment: Why don't you use a calculator and find out?

Comment: @barakmanos, ok, so the correct result ends in `295`, not `296`. Do you think that adds to my confusion? :)

Answer (score 3):

When you count up to $2^{32}$, you start counting $1$, $2$, ... then the $2^{32}$th number is $2^{32}$.
Since the computer has to store the number $0$ in an unsigned int, it is actually starting to count with $0$, then $1$ and so on. That means that the $n$th number for the computer is, in fact, $n-1$. Hence, the biggest number it can store, the $2^{32}$th number is $2^{32}-1$